# How to retrieve data from Postgresql index using java

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, java, jdbc

I am writing an application for searching, using text search of Postgresql. I am a beginner in Database. I created a Gin index and i am trying to get data from it. My code is

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class JDBCPostgressRetrieve {

    private static String Database = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/search";
    private static String user = "postgres";
    private static String password = "abcd";

    public static String getDatabase() {
        return Database;
    }

    public static String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void retrieve(int limit) {

        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet rs = null; 
        int i = 0;
        try {

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? "
                    + "Include in your library path!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    JDBCPostgressRetrieve.getDatabase(),
                    JDBCPostgressRetrieve.getUser(),
                    JDBCPostgressRetrieve.getPassword());

            if (connection == null) {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            } else {

                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();

                // Creating Statement for query execution
                stmt = connection.createStatement();
                // creating Query String                
                String query = "SELECT (person_name,email,mobile_number,key_skills,current_employer)\n" +
                                "FROM bhubneshwar\n" +
                                "WHERE textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery('MBA & HR')\n" +
                                "LIMIT 10";

                // excecuting query
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    // Didplaying data of tables
                    System.out.println("Name : " + rs.getString("person_name"));
                    System.out.println("email : " + rs.getString("email"));
                    System.out.println("mobile_number : " + rs.getString("mobile_number"));
                    System.out.println("key_skills : " + rs.getString("key_skills"));
                    System.out.println("current_employer : " + rs.getString("current_employer"));
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                connection.close();
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("SQLException while closing connection. "+ e.getMessage());
            }           
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args []) {
        JDBCPostgressRetrieve ret = new JDBCPostgressRetrieve();
        ret.retrieve(100);
    }
}
```

textsearchable_index_col is the index column in the table. But after running the code I am getting an error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name person_name was not found in this ResultSet.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.findColumn(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2727)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getString(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2567)
at com.presciencesoft.postgres.search.JDBCPostgressRetrieve.retrieve(JDBCPostgressRetrieve.java:77)
at com.presciencesoft.postgres.search.JDBCPostgressRetrieve.main(JDBCPostgressRetrieve.java:103)
```

In this way can I retrieve from index as table ?? This query is running perfectly in command prompt.

Comment: The `( )` around the selected columns looks strange to me. Please try and run this on the command line, chances are 95% of the code you posted isn't relevant (and we're not all Java developers here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses form a row-constructor, so your query returns a single column row literal, essentially an anonymous composite type.

Compare:

```
regress=> SELECT (1,2);
  row  
-------
 (1,2)
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT 1, 2;
 ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------
        1 |        2
(1 row)
```

You would've quickly realised this if you'd run the query on the `psql` command line (or in PgAdmin-III if you prefer GUIs).

A second misunderstanding: You don't retrieve data from an index<sup>1</sup>. You get data from a *table*. The database engine might used any indexes that are present to speed your query up, but you're still getting data from the table. You can see this if you `explain` a command to get its query plan.

<sup>1</sup>: *... well, arguably until PostgreSQL 9.2's with index-only scans, but that's a bit of an implementation detail.*

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Nice explanation